# user defined function php

Tags: php, function, parsing

I have two files 'inc.core.php' and 'index.php'.i have defined a function in 'inc.core.php' as :

```
function isLoggedin() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_name'])){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
   }
}
```

i want to use the function in index and tried as:

```
require "inc.core.php";

if(isLoggedin()){

  header('Location:patient.html');

}
```

but it keeps giving me error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\medfinal\inc.core.php on line 6

Comment: So what code do you have on the lines above your `isLoggedin()` function in the `inc.core.php` file? e.g. lines 1-5 of the file.... edit that extra information into your question

Comment: Damn, i forgot a semi-colon above,feeling terrible and thank you very much,Sir.!!!

Comment: why you are not put isLoggedin() function inside a class

Comment: i just started learning php, right now i am just following tutorials and i am yet to learn how to use classes

Comment: Just a suggestion, look for and follow as new tutorials as you could find if you don't want to revise your knowledge after a while, as some older tutorials will teach you in wrong way, like in using php mysql functions (currently deprecated) and not mysqli instead. Starting with object oriented programming would make you get used to newer php codes faster as well.